# Jquery calculate days with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How is it possible to calculate the total days using interval intitial and final DatePicker. Sorry for my bad english

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: [3,1],
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);


            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $("#input1").val(dateText);
                $("#input2").val("");
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
                $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
                $("#input1").val( dateText );
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else {
                $("#input2").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            }
        }
    });
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk](http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/)

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: You can try *Moment.js*. `console.log(moment($("#input1").val()).diff(moment(selectedDate), "days"));`

Comment: I want to calculate the time since this method http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4UZaJ/

Comment: this is my example http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk

Comment: @Ion, you need to calculate number of days. right?

Comment: @Rajesh, yes, using this example http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk and this method jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4UZaJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to compute date difference in days is the following:

```
  var t1 = Date.parse($("#input1").val()); // date1.getTime();
  var t2 = Date.parse($("#input2").val()); // date2.getTime();
  var difference = Math.abs(t2 - t1) / 86400000;
  $("#diff").val(difference);
```

(I tested by putting the code as the last lines of `onSelect: function(dateText, inst)`).

`86400000` is the computed for `24h x 60min x 60s x 1000ms` (number of milliseconds in a day)

Comment: Great! You can add an extra condition to check the negative value or use Math.abs(difference)

Comment: @abhiagNitk - I have edited the answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank Yoy for answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with dates you should look into `moment.js`.

You can try something like this:

#### Moment

```
moment($("#input1").val()).diff(moment(selectedDate), "days");
```

#### Pure JS

```js
var d1 = new Date(date1);
var d2 = new Date(selectedDate);
var secInDays = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
d1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
d2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log((+d2 - +d1) / secInDays)
```

Comment: What does d1.setHours(0,0,0,0) do? please explain.

Comment: It resets time value in date object. When you do new Date(), it will initialize date and time but when you do new Date(...) It only sets time. In such cases, diff will have 1 extra value.